# How to sort an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I want to sort an NSMutableArray.
The following is the structure of the array.

An array includes some dictionaries those have two variables with keys like this.

```
NSMutableArray array - NSDictionary dic - int num(key: @"Num"), NSString str(key: @"Str")
```

How do I sort the array by the num value of the dictionary?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward… did you try something that didn't work?

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date"  ascending:NO];
    [searchTableData sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

Answer (score 0):

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id dic1, id dic2) {
    return [dic1 objectForKey:@"Num"] <= [dic2 objectForKey:@"Num"];
}];
```

but you really should use `NSNumber` instead of `int` for `@"Num"` and use

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id dic1, id dic2) {
    return [[dic1 objectForKey:@"Num"] intValue] <= [[dic2 objectForKey:@"Num"] intValue];
}];
```

instead.